# CSS3PIE & HTML5shiv printing issues IE8

Tags: printing, internet-explorer-8, css3pie, html5shiv

I'm having problems using CSS3PIE & HTML5shiv for this huge website. It comes down to printing issues in IE8. Whenever I want to print a webpage, IE8 just seems to crash. I've done some research and this printing crash seems related to the use of CSS3PIE and HTML5shiv.

Any way I can avoid this problem in IE8? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've turned off Shiv and it still happens. So it seems to be more CSS3PIE-related.

Comment: This is a known issue in CSS3pie they have fixed it in IE9.